# Json updating in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift4.2

Aim is convert innerJson to Array<[String:Any]>. What is the mistake in this? please help

```
var outerJson:String? = "{\"outerkey1\":\"Air France\",\"innerJson\":\"[{\\\"innerJsonKey1\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"innerJsonKey2\\\":{\\\"businessPurpose\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Testing \\\"}},{\\\"innerJsonKey1\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"innerJsonKey2\\\":{\\\"businessPurpose\\\":null,\\\"description\\\":null}}]\",\"AirClass\":\"null\",\"FromTo\":\"Utti (QVY)\\/Umea (UME)\"}"
var convertedDict:[String:Any]?
if let data = outerJson?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

    do {
        convertedDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]
        //print(convertedDict)
    } catch {
        //CALogger.dPrint(error)
    }
}
//print(convertedDict?["innerJson"] as Any)
var array = convertedDict?["innerJson"] as? Array<[String:Any]>
print(array)
```

Comment: @Pramod, tried. did not work.

Comment: Unrelated but you can delete the entire `options` parameter. None of those options is relevant in Swift if the expected type is a collection type.

Comment: you are getting Array as String in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the JSON carefully. The value for key `innerJson` is a(nother JSON) **`String`**, not an array. The multiline literal string syntax makes it clearer.

You have to apply JSONSerialization twice

```
let outerJson = """
{"outerkey1":"Air France","innerJson":"[{\\"innerJsonKey1\\":\\"1\\",\\"innerJsonKey2\\":{\\"businessPurpose\\":\\"Test\\",\\"description\\":\\"Testing \\"}},{\\"innerJsonKey1\\":\\"2\\",\\"innerJsonKey2\\":{\\"businessPurpose\\":null,\\"description\\":null}}]","AirClass":"null","FromTo":"Utti (QVY)\\/Umea (UME)"}
"""


let data = Data(outerJson.utf8)
do {
    if let outerDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
        let innerJSON = outerDict["innerJson"] as? String {
        if let innerArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(innerJSON.utf8)) as? [[String:Any]] {
            print(innerArray)
        }
    }
} catch {
    //CALogger.dPrint(error)
}
```

Comment: already working on same after seeing your comment. thanks champ @vadian

Answer (score 0):

```swift
var outerJson:String? = "{\"outerkey1\":\"Air France\",\"innerJson\":\"[{\\\"innerJsonKey1\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"innerJsonKey2\\\":{\\\"businessPurpose\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Testing \\\"}},{\\\"innerJsonKey1\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"innerJsonKey2\\\":{\\\"businessPurpose\\\":null,\\\"description\\\":null}}]\",\"AirClass\":\"null\",\"FromTo\":\"Utti (QVY)\\/Umea (UME)\"}"

var convertedDict:[String:Any]?

if let data = outerJson?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

    do {
        convertedDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.mutableContainers,.allowFragments,.mutableLeaves]) as? [String: Any]
        //print(convertedDict)
    } catch {
        //CALogger.dPrint(error)
    }
}

// Create a new array of type [<String, Any>] from the convertedDict dictionary 
let arrayOfDicts = convertedDict?.map { [$0.key: $0.value] }

print(arrayOfDicts)
```

Comment: converted dict is a dictionary and i'm able to array["innerJson"], but i want to convert array["innerJson"] to an Array<[String:Any]>

Comment: @RamcharanReddy, I have edited my answer. Please let me know if this helps.